# Override interface property with constructor parameter with different name

Tags: kotlin

I have this code:

```
class AnyUsernamePersistentNodePath(override val value: String) : AnyPersistenceNodePath {
    override val key = "username"    
}
```

and

```
interface AnyPersistenceNodePath {
    val key: String
    val value: String
}
```

So far, so good. Now I want parameter `value` in the constructor to be named `username`, instead of `value`. But, obviously, keep overriding interface's property `value`. Is that possible in Kotlin?

I know that I can do:

```
class AnyUsernamePersistentNodePath(val username: String) : AnyPersistenceNodePath {
    override val key = "username"
    override val value = username
}
```

but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: you don't say what/why you are trying to avoid something.  what part of it do you not like?

Comment: @JaysonMinard Actually, it is because I have started learning Kotlin and I'd like to know if this kind of things are possible.

Comment: ok, then my answer below is the smallest syntax I'm aware of...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do what you want simply by removing `val` from the constructor parameter, so that it is a parameter and not a member.  Your final class would be:

```kotlin
class AnyUsernamePersistentNodePath(username: String) : AnyPersistenceNodePath {
    override val key = "username"
    override val value = username
}
```

You cannot otherwise change the name of something that you are truly overriding.  But you can pass in the value to be assigned to a member later during construction, as my slightly modified version of your code shows.